# Puma-dev not working on xip.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

With `pow`, I could access my app on another computer or phone on the same network at `myapp.192.168.xx.xip.io`, and it worked just fine.

But since switching to Rails 5 and `puma-dev`, it doesn't work. The browser gives me the error `cannot open the page because the server can't be found.` If I refresh the page, then I get `could not open the page because the server stopped responding.`

If I go to `myapp.192.168.xx.xip.io` instead of `myapp.dev` on the machine running the server, it works, but it won't work on my phone on the same network.

This worked fine with `pow`. What's different with `puma-dev`?

EDIT:

`netstat -an | grep LISTEN` gives:

```
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9253         *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.443                  *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5432         *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  ::1.5432               *.*                    LISTEN
```

P.S. The tag `puma-dev` hasn't been created yet, otherwise I would of used it.

Comment: Is Puma listening on `::1` or `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Maybe. How do I know and what do I do to change it?

Comment: `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` usually tells you what's active and what port it's listening on. Does it say `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: @tadman see updated question

Comment: You're going to have to better define "won't work" since that's too vague.

Comment: when trying to access `myapp.192.168.1.5.xip.io` on another computer on the same network, I get an error: `could not open the page because the server stopped responding.` There is nothing in the log at `log/development.log` to indicate that the server is getting a request